# What is the best interval size to consider in calculating the probabilities of a normally distributed sample?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I have a sample of size 80 which is normally distributed. I want to calculate the probabilities on different intervals. Is there any way or method of finding the most optimum interval size?  Meaning that how should we know how many intervals should we consider between Min and Max of the sample?
Another question is should we remove outliers first and then make decisions about the number of intervals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you divide the domain into intervals separated by a standard deviation $\sigma$:
[image]

then you get 8 intervals separated by a commonly used statistical measure.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful.